# Use iterator for take fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### I want to iterate for save information inside of each appropriate field.

Let me explain:

I have an array inside `list_of_fields` with something like `["name_of_field1", "name_of_field2", "name_of_field3"]`,

Then,

I want to use that array to run it inside a bucle as this:

```
list_of_fields.each do |field|
 user_info_notification.form_data = {note: records[:"#{field}"]}
end
```

and save the info that already is in `records.fieldname` inside user_info_notification cause i must send dynamically info from a register to other in other table. The array have the field names.

Comment: and you are struggling with..?

Comment: what do you mean @potashin

Comment: @MarcosR.Guevara: he means "what's even the question here?". You just posted some code. What were we to do with it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i want to use `field` iterator to return the field name, the iterator have a list of names, with each one of this fields i can add info that can save it on DB register.

Comment: @MarcosR.Guevara: and what you have there, it doesn't work? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `records` is a hash, there are 2 possibilities, the keys are `symbol` or `string`, thus

if symbol

```
{ note: records[field.to_sym] }
```

if string, you don't have to convert to anything,

```
{ note: records[field] }
```